# ASP.NET connect to Windows Application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, wcf

Because i cannot detect printer with ASP.NET(C#) on Client Side. So I have created a small Window Application in C# to detect all printer on Client side and print the document.

in other side i have a ASP.NET.

My idea when the user clic the boutton on ASP.NET it call Window Application print function via WCF. is that possible ? is anyone has an Example ?

Thanks you in adavance,
Stev

Answer (score 1):

I think that better thing to do is to use some sort of web reporting engine (eg. [fyiReporting](http://www.fyireporting.com/), open source) and generate PDF for print, or special page that will render html for print and let the browser do the printing.

Your ASP.NET application can't call local windows application, you can periodicaly check for pending printing jobs in ASP.NET application by calling some page / handler / something in ASP.NET application from Windows app, but IMO this approach has many obvious downsides.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows Application also contains a WCF service and the port the WCF service is listening on is not blocked by the users firewall. Then yes it's possible, but seems way to much trouble compared to what you're trying to do, personally I would rather use ActiveX, and that's something I don't do without a bottle of painkillers next to me :)

Why don't you just render the content to a new page and let the user use the browser to print it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easy way would be to use a javascript function showb below in your web page associated with a button click that does the following:

```
function print()
{
    window.print()
}
```